# Ajax -changing values of disabled textbox on selecting autocomplete

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have written code for autocomplete in a text box. My problem is how to assign values to a disabled text box based upon autocomplete selection. I have two entities product name and product price. Product name is on autocomplete. product price should be dynamically changing according to autocomplete selection.

```
<tr>
  <td class="header" align="left" valign="top">
   Enter the product<span class="required">*</span>
  </td>
  <td>
   <input class="text" type="text" name="product" id="tag" value="" align="left"  size="75" maxlength="80">
  </td>
  <td class="header" align="left" valign="top">
    price
 </td><td>
   <input class="text" disabled type="text" name="price"  value="" align="left" size="75" maxlength="80">
 </td>
 </tr>
```

Jquery Autocomplete (autocomplete.php echoes values of my product say xyz abc def )

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(){
 $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    selectFirst: true
 });
});
 </script>
```

Should I echo my autocomplete.php as xyz 100 abc 212 def 200 ? 
Any help would be highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the select function.

```
$("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
    source: "your link to the json feed here",
    selectFirst: true
    select: function( event, ui ) {
       $( "#element_needs_editing" ).val(ui.item.value);
       return false;
    }
 });
```

Also, you will need to edit your autocomplete.php is json format. With a `value` field it could probably hold the text or an id or something. With the array, you can send more than one variable to the front page.
Best is to load the result in to an array and echo it out using `json_encode($array);`

Your search output needs to be on json format. The best way to achieve this is to load all the search result values in to an array and send it through json_encode.

```
<?php
//A simple array
$data = array();
$data[0]['value'] = 1;
$data[0]['item_code'] = "A001";
$data[0]['price'] = 15;
$data[1]['value'] = 2;
$data[1]['item_code'] = "A002";
$data[1]['price'] = 20;
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

The above will result in the below output which jquery will use.

```
[{"value":1,"item_code":"A001","price":15},{"value":2,"item_code":"A002","price":20}]
```

Now if you want to refer to the "Item Code" you simply have to refer to

```
$( "#element_with_item_code" ).val(ui.item.item_code);
```

or price

```
$( "#element_with_price" ).val(ui.item.price);
```

Comment: I am extremely new to json and ajax. I would be happy if you could share some examples relative to this qn.

Comment: Check out <http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#custom-data>. It has a demo of what I believe that you will be needing.

Comment: Yeah I have done this auto-complete on my own. But the thing is there is another disabled text box for price , which  changes its value according to the selected product dynamically.

Comment: Let me try to do some jsfiddle

Comment: Thanks very much for the efforts. This is exactly am looking for. I want to know how can I assign the values for projects dynamically from autocomplete.php .. In other words how could I call autocomplete.php from javascript to assign the values for projects[]. This could solve my entire problem.

Comment: Check the "source" line I added

Comment: Thanks, I have autocomplete.php (ajax output file) which is printing values of the product name dynamically from my db. (in our case jquery,jquery-ui,sizzlejs.) Could you please show me how should I call server-side script (autocomplete.php) and assign the values of "var projects"

Comment: Check the edited answer. The source will act as the projects element in the demo. I have also shown a simple php array and how it should be used for the php output.

Answer (score 0):

try something like this

```
        $(document).ready(function(){
             $("#tag").autocomplete("autocomplete.php", {
                selectFirst: true,
                select: function( event, ui ) {
                    if(ui.item){
                        document.getElementsByName('price')[0].value = ui.item.value
                    }
                }
             });
        })
```